# Keeping Android Studio up to date with an upstream Github Repo

Tags: android, android-studio, github

Not sure I have worded the title correctly. Here is my situation:

1) Forked a Github repository I do not control, in order to fix a bug, then hopefully have a Pull Request approved and merged with this repo.

2) Clone my forked repo into Android Studio project on my computer.

3) Made some changes.

4) The upstream repo I do not control has also made some changes, so I want to update/ fetch those so I can make sure my changes do not conflict.

5) What is the best way to fetch those changes? Merge them with my local copy, push to my upstream master on Github, so I can do a Pull Request without worrying about merge conflict with updated code in the original project that I have not merged with my fork?

6) Basically I cannot work out if Android Studio has any idea their repo exists, as it only seems to be aware of my fork.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/syncing-a-fork/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I couldn't find an answer anywhere on Stack Overflow, so figured I would answer my own question, but would love some added detail, specifically as to whether what I did is possible using Android Studio's GUI.

From Terminal:

```
git remote add upstream https://github.com[repository_name].git

git fetch upstream

git checkout master

git merge upstream/master
```

I think this has worked, hopefully I have not broken the upstream repo I don't control

Comment: thanks @MartinZeitler, that seems like the easiest thing to do for now. I figure their must be a way to do it all through the Android Studio GUI, will post update when I figure it out

Comment: just create that shell/batch script and then add it as an "external command"... then it has a button.

Comment: that is common functionality of an IDE ...it works with just any of them.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is go to VCS -> Git -> Remotes and then add the link to your upstream.

When you want to pull from it, it's almost the same except you change the remote from origin to upstream.